# how do I get my php array to json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make my json output in the following format below, but I do not know how to code it to make it display in just format... I just have the values, any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
{
    "firstcolumn":"56036",
    "loc":"Deli",
    "lastA":"Activity",
    "mTime":"2011-02-01 11:59:26.243",
    "nTime":"2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Time":"2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Age":"9867 Hour(s)",
    "ction":"                                                  ",
    "nTime":null
},
{
    "firstcolumn":"56036",
    "loc":"Deli",
    "lastA":"Activity",
    "mTime":"2011-02-01 11:59:26.243",
    "nTime":"2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Time":"2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Age":"9867 Hour(s)",
    "ction":"                                                  ",
    "nTime":null
}
```

Comment: To make a PHP array into JSON you do `json_encode()`.

Comment: I understand that, but how do i setup my php array so when i encode it it looks like that

Comment: ask `var_dump(json_decode('string with needed json', true));`

Comment: We cannot possible answer that because we don't know how/where you're getting your data or forming your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PHP **associative array** to set the key => value's of your array to be converted to json. As you would expect the key of the php associative array becomes the key of the JSON object, and the same with the values.

```
$array = array(
    'firstcolumn' => '56036',
    "loc" => "Deli",
    "lastA" => "Activity",
    "mTime" => "2011-02-01 11:59:26.243",
    "nTime" => "2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Time" => "2011-02-01 10:57:02.0",
    "Age" => "9867 Hour(s)",
    "ction" => "",
    "nTime" => NULL
);
```

You can do both arrays like this (using previous array to show concept but can replace with that same `array()`)

```
$array2 = $array1;
$array2['firstcolumn'] = "56037";
$botharrays = array($array, $array2);
```

What we just did is put both sub arrays into one containing array so that when you encode the json it has each object separately.

> array( array1, array2 )

Then use `json_encode()` to encode the array into the json format you requested

```
$JSON= json_encode($array);
```

or

```
$json = json_encode($botharrays);
```

Comment: thanks for this, how do I add another set of arrays into that $array?

Comment: @thevoipman Just loop through your data setting an array of arrays. Pass the array of arrays just like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$json = json_encode($myArray);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: You "think"? Shouldn't you be more positive?